# Remove empty strings from tuples inside a list

Tags: python, regex, list, tuples

Right now I have three lists that are generated from a RE findall function, and I am trying to remove some of the empty strings from the tuples inside the list. And the numbers should be converted to integer in the process too:

Got:`[('', '', '1', '1')]`

Expected: `[(1, 1)]`

Got: `[('', '', '20', '500'), ('21', 'failed', '', '')]`

Expected: `[(20, 500), (21, 'failed')]`

Got: `[('3', 'failed', '', ''), ('', '', '48', '23'), ('', '', '96', '0')]`

expected: `[(3, 'failed'), (48, 23), (96, 0)]`

Any ideas?

Comment: Which regex are you using? Why not use one that doesn't match the empty string in the first place instead of filtering them out afterwards?

Comment: I tried my best...But I cannot write out a different regex...

Comment: Well, maybe we can help you with that?

Comment: mission_report('Yes, mission 3 failed. Raid 48 was accomplished: targets found: 23. mission 96 was accomplished, targets found: 0') should return [(3,'failed'), (48, 23), (96, 0)]). The regex I wrote for this was: match=re.findall(r'(?:raid|mission) (\d+) (failed)|(\d+) (?:was )?accomplished.*?found: (\d+)', s, re.IGNORECASE)

Comment: Ah, OK, so there will always be two empty backreferences. I see. Well then let's do it your way...hang on a second.

Answer (score 8):

A nested list comprehension with a tuple constructor:

```
>>> lst = [('', '', '20', '500'), ('21', 'failed', '', '')]
>>> [(tuple(int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in _ if x)) for _ in lst]
[(20, 500), (21, 'failed')]
```

---

For each tuple (`_`) in `lst`, construct a `tuple` with a generator expression. The tuple constructor alone is below:

```
tuple(int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in _ if x)
```

Which seems confusing, but I'll break it down. For each string `x` in tuple `_` (which is a tuple in `lst`), construct a tuple. `if x` checks to see if the string is not empty. (If string `x` is empty, `x` is false.) `if x`, the generator expression will produce either `x` or `int(x)` depending on whether `x` in question is a digit in string form. (Trying to turn a non-numeric string into an integer will result in an exception.)

For each tuple `_` in `lst`, the generator creates a new, identical tuple, except the empty, false strings are filtered out and any digit strings are converted into `int`s.

Above code is equivalent to:

```
new_lst = []

for _ in lst: # For each tuple in lst
    for x in _: # For each string in tuple
        temp_tuple = ()
        if x: # Only add to tuple if string is not empty
            if x.isdigit(): # If x is a digit in string form
                temp_tuple += (int(x),) # Convert to int
            else:
                temp_tuple += (x,) # Keep string
    new_lst.append(temp_tuple)
```

Comment: you guys care to explain a bit?

Comment: it returns [(500,), ()]

Comment: @user3238319 You'll have to edit your code with the exact input and output. Just ran my code at the beginning of the file again, and it worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
def sanitize(t):                                
    for i in t:
        try:
            yield int(i)
        except ValueError:
            yield i

inputs = [('3', 'failed', '', ''), ('', '', '48', '23'), ('', '', '96', '0')]
map(tuple, map(sanitize, [filter(None, i) for i in inputs]))
```

Gives output of:

```
[(3, 'failed'), (48, 23), (96, 0)]
```

`filter` is a function that operates on a sequence and returns only the "truthy" elements. Empty strings are falsy. Map is another function that takes a sequence and runs each element in that sequence through a given function. In this case the function `sanitize` which converts a string to a int if it can or else just returns the string.

We are using `yield` rather than `return` in the `sanitize` function as an easy way to return yet another sequence to the next map function. Alternatively we could build a list inside the function and return it.

Comment: I tested it in a shell before submitting it, so it works. You'd have to post your actual code for me to tell what's wrong. Try stripping off the layers and figure out which one isn't working. Debug! Use a Python console for this kind of thing.

Comment: Just double checked again, copied that exact code into a terminal and ran it. Works fine. I'll reformat it to not show the output if you like.

Comment: This is returning map object. I guess it has something to with python version.

Comment: That's right, this is Python 2, if you wrap `list` around it you'll get the output specified.